# Python SQL TypeError: can't concat list to bytes

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to open a SQL template in Python which creates a database with tables and excutes using pymsql. However, I keep getting an error.

```
import pymysql
import Settings

with open('Settings/databasetemplate.sql', 'r') as sql_file:
    sql = sql_file.read()
conn = pymysql.connect(host='*****', user='*****', password='*****')
cur = conn.cursor()
print(sql)
cur.execute(sql.split(';'))
conn.commit()
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Projects\Jupiter\Test.py", line 9, in <module>
>     cur.execute(sql.split(';'))   File "D:\Projects\Jupiter\Enviroment\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
> line 158, in execute
>     result = self._query(query)   File "D:\Projects\Jupiter\Enviroment\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
> line 325, in _query
>     conn.query(q)   File "D:\Projects\Jupiter\Enviroment\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> line 548, in query
>     self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)   File "D:\Projects\Jupiter\Enviroment\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> line 817, in _execute_command
>     packet = prelude + sql[: packet_size - 1] TypeError: can't concat list to bytes
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is `databasetemplate.sql` a binary and/or unicode file?

Comment: How do I find that out mate?

Comment: One way is just to look at the contents and see if it contains any characters that aren't plain ASCII (i.e. accented spanish/european letters), although they can be hard to spot by just looking.

Comment: Try adding `.decode()` to the end of  the read call, like this `sql = sql_file.read().decode()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split the commands by the semicolon, but if there's a reason you need to, you can run the commands individually:

```py
for command in sql.split(';'):
    cur.execute(command)
```

Comment: Hi mate, i'm just going on a example from Stackoverflow, however even removing the .split doesn't work.

Comment: Did the seperate command execution work?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: See if it works on a fresh DB, running just one command (instead of running all of them)

Comment: That's correct. It works with just one command however I'm trying to insert a full database with table structures. Any advice?

Comment: Unfourtunately not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254226/discussion-between-zurgeg-and-nixfee).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, as there was multiple lines to query from the SQL. It was only doing the whole file and not line by line. Therefore, with pymysql I changed my code to:

```
import pymysql
import Settings
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT

conn = pymysql.connect(host='***', user='***', password='***', client_flag=CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS)
with open('Settings/databasetemplate.sql', 'r') as f:
     with conn.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute(f.read())
     conn.commit()
```